# Custom Author Loop

Tags: author, list-authors

Essentially what I'd like to do is have the same effect as the wp_list_authors tag, but instead of just listing the name or their post count, I want to be able to do a loop with the IDs. Ultimately I'd like have to a page with every author, with their name, description, avatar and link. I can figure out the specifics, I just need a way to do something like:

```
foreach $author as $author->ID
```

Thanks in advance,

Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you'll want to use [get_users](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) and you might want to take a look at the source code behind [wp_list_authors](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/author-template.php#L271) to info on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `WP_User_Query` to [loop through users](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query). You can pull user meta data (anything stored in the user profile) through this class - and you can also limit by user role/level (IE, run a different query for admins, editors, subscribers, etc.)